# How to get list of attribute names and attribute values from tag?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML tag contains multiple attributes:

```
<textarea id="text" name="comment" class="form-control" style="color:#959595" ... ></textarea>
```

How can I get list of all attribute name & attribute values by pure JavaScript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as that:

```
var element = document.getElementById('text');
var attributes = element.attributes; // This now contains map of attributes of your DOM element
```

Answer (score 0):

There is way but you need to know ID of the tag

```
var tag = document.getElementById("text");
var atts = tag.attributes;
```